# Solving integral equation $y(t) = e^t ( 1 + \int_0^t e^{-\tau} y(\tau)d \tau )$ with Laplace transform

Tags: integration, laplace-transform, convolution

> Solve the integral equation $$y(t) = e^t \bigg(1+ \int_0^t e^{-\tau}\ y(\tau) d \tau \bigg)$$

The apporach that stands out to me is using the convolution theorem and laplace transforms. Im able to arrive at the expression $$y(t) = e^t + e^t*y(t)$$ But Im unsure what do next. From my understanding you can't factor out $e^t$ in this case?

Comment: We know $y’(t)=e^t+e^{-t}y(t)-y(0)$

Comment: @HenryLee Are you sure about the $-y(0)$ term?

Comment: Or if we use what you said, $(1-e^t)y=e^t$ so $y=\frac{e^t}{1-e^t}$

Comment: @Botond yes because when we differentiate the integral we get the function of the upper bound minus the function of the lower bound

Comment: @HenryLee but by the FTC1, if $F(x)=\int_{a}^{x} f(t) \mathrm{d}t$, then $F'(x)=f(x)$.

Comment: I agree with Botond.

Comment: Sorry, I made an error when typing in the equation. Should make more sense now with regards to the convolution theorem.

Comment: Oh it’s a really different equation now

Answer (score 0):

$$y(t) = e^t \bigg(1+ \int_0^t e^{-\tau}\ y(\tau) d \tau \bigg)$$
$$y'(t) = e^t \bigg(1+ \int_0^t e^{-\tau}\ y(\tau) d \tau \bigg) + y(t) = 2y(t) \implies y(t)=Ce^{2t}$$

Substitute into the original equation to find $C=1$.

$$Ce^{2t} = e^t \bigg(1+ C\int_0^t e^{\tau} d \tau \bigg)$$
$$Ce^{t} = 1+ C\left(e^t-1\right) \implies C=1$$

Answer (score 0):

Let the Laplace of y(t) be Y(s).

Applying Laplace on both the sides we end up with

\begin{align}
> Y(s)&= \frac{1}{s-1}+(L[e^t])(L[y(t)])\\
    \end{align}
\begin{align}
> Y(s)&= \frac{1}{s-1}+\frac{1}{s-1}Y(s)\\
    \end{align}
Solving we end up in,

\begin{align}
> Y(s)&= \frac{1}{s-2}\\
    \end{align}
Taking inverse Laplace we get,
y(t)=e<sup>2t</sup>

Comment: How come you can do $L(e^t)L(y(t))$? Don't you have to take $L(y(t)e^t)$ and then use convolution?